# Sending email to a SAP inbox and an ordinary email inbox

Tags: email, abap

I needed a function to send an email to an ordinary email address and to send on too to an SAP Inbox. I found this function:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_ATT_SEND_API1'
            EXPORTING
              document_data              = gd_doc_data
              put_in_outbox              = 'X'
              commit_work                = 'X'
            TABLES
              packing_list               = it_packing_list
              contents_txt               = it_message
              receivers                  = it_receivers
            EXCEPTIONS
              too_many_receivers         = 1
              document_not_sent          = 2
              document_type_not_exist    = 3
              operation_no_authorization = 4
              parameter_error            = 5
              x_error                    = 6
              enqueue_error              = 7
              OTHERS                     = 8.
```

The it_receivers it's filled like this:

```
 FREE wa_it_receivers.
        wa_it_receivers-receiver   = sy-uname.  "&----- Assign SAP User Id
        wa_it_receivers-rec_type   = 'B'.                    "&-- Send to SAP Inbox
        wa_it_receivers-com_type   = 'INT'.
        wa_it_receivers-notif_del  = 'X'.
        wa_it_receivers-notif_ndel = 'X'.
        APPEND wa_it_receivers TO it_receivers .
```

This only send's the email to the SAP inbox. I went to the domain of the rec_type field to see which letter is so it can send the email to an ordinary email account. I believe it is 'A' but, as it only says external address. Is that the one? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a nice example of how to do it [wiki.sdn.sap.com](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/Send+Message+to+External+email+id+and+SAP+User+id+via+ABAP)

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting. I'm going to check it out.

Comment: I've seen the code in that link and it worked! Just needed to alter somethings in regard the external email like making a loop to get all the email from a table, but it was very simple. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: By the way, any thougths on how tho change the name of the sender? Thanks

Comment: @EvaDias The function module `SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_ATT_SEND_API1` calls directly other function module which is `SO_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1`. In the second one you have an option to pass sender address in parameters `SENDER_ADDRESS` and `SENDER_ADDRESS_TYPE`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why people keep on digging up that old function module. I'd always recommend using the Business Communication Services API - it's [well documented](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_06/helpdata/en/4d/353bcfd2512304e10000000a15822b/content.htm) and much easier to use. The docs also contain an example on [how to send to an external mail address](http://help.sap.com/erp2005_ehp_06/helpdata/en/4d/3508df467e6e4ae10000000a42189c/content.htm).

Comment: I'm sorry but I found it on the web. Looke easy to follow and seamed to do exactly what I need. Has I said, I'm learning about ABAP and SAP just for a bit now, so I'm not familiar with things that are old or not. That's why I post my doubts here. Thanks.

Comment: No need to be sorry about it :-)

Comment: @vwegert any idea how to change sender as email adress in oo ?

Comment: @Mtok ...with the appropriate method? ;-)

Comment: ok I made it thanks. I'm not sure if what I made is appropriate because you always discredit what I did, rightfully :) Thanks.

Comment: @Mtok You show no signs of having researched anything, you don't tell the world what you'Ve already tried - so please tell me why I should bother spending time to investigate YOUR problem in depth?

Comment: Hi @vwegert! I think you misunderstood me or I mistold myself because of my English which is not that good sometimes. I'm telling you that you accustomed me to think whether the methods I use are obsolete or right method and up to date. I think 'discredit' word in my last comment was wrong. It should be 'criticise'. Anyways, thanks again.