# Change the sender for an external email in SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_ATT_SEND_API1 function

Tags: email, abap

I'm using SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_ATT_SEND_API1 function to send an email with an attachment both for a sap user and for an external email. So far, so good. I discovered that the sender of these emails is the sap user that fired the report and the function doesn't have the sender exportation parameter like the old SO_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1 has. The problem is that I need the sender to be an external email. I've been searching and couldn't make this happen. Can anyone help or give me an idea? Thanks

Comment: with all the respect: I'm not saying that your question is not pertinent or not valid but the sequence of your questions make me suggest you to read carefully StackOverflow FAQ. Here people are willing to help you and if you request help of them why not listen what they say? However questions should be good enough and not being to specific to our requirements. Again, I'm not saying this because of this particular question and I agree this is not the best way of saying that but it must be said. I'm sure reading the FAQ again will make your questions more valuable and get more answers

Answer (score 2):

As I have already stated in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941481/218890) to another question of yours, stop using the old API and use the new BCS API. The documentation contains an [example on how to change the sender address](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/f5/e16f3a53dee246e10000000a11402f/frameset.htm):

```
DATA: lr_send_request TYPE REF TO cl_bcs,
      lr_sender       TYPE REF TO cl_cam_address_bcs.

lr_sender = cl_cam_address_bcs=>create_internet_address( 'foo.bar@baz.com' ).
lr_send_request->set_sender( lr_sender ).
```

Just try to copy the example report `BCS_EXAMPLE_1` to your local namespace and exchange the line that sets the sender (line 50 in my release, might be a different one on your system).